# Need help- iFrame app url index.php not work

Tags: url-routing, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-iframe

I am trying to create simple Facebook app using the php sdk 3.0.

I followed the instruction from http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-3-0-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/ to create my own app. I added my appid, secret, baseurl as the documentation said. I upload all code to my free host.

- Canvasurl is "http://quang56.000space.com/fbjs"
- canvas page is http://apps.facebook.com/first_app_quang/

The browser said that webpage not available but my index.php file still in the host. I upload another file to check version of php (http://quang56.000space.com/fbjs/info.php) and it works.

I also tried changing index.php to index.html so the file is available but app still did not work.

What can the problem be?

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that the framework requires the CURL PHP extension.

> [message:protected] => Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension.

Here's a tutorial on how to install the CURL PHP extension.  (it's 2.5 years old...hope it still works for you)

http://www.ivankristianto.com/os/ubuntu/howto-install-curl-in-php-apache/379/

Comment: thank for your help, app is ok now, i just change host support curl and it's ok, many thank